# Auth::attempt() Manually Authenticating Users based on NULL condition | Laravel | Passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am creating an application based on Laravel 5.8. I want to manually authentication users based on some checks, But these checks or fields have some null values or not null values.
I follow the official documentation [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#authenticating-users)

Instead of checking like this

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

I want to check if some fields that are not null like

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'activate_on' => 'SomeDateTimeValue Or Not Null' ])) {

}
```

So it means if the user has some activate_on fields value which should not Null then the Auth::attempt should return true otherwise false.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding your implementation of the `UserProvider` interface, but that's a lot of work.

I think the easiest way is to do it in two steps.

```
// first get the user by email
$user = User::whereEmail($email)->first();

if($user->activate_on && Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])
{
    // logged in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe what you are asking is directly possible.  If you take a look at the `retrieveByCredentials()` method which is called during the `attempt()` process, the query builder is only set up to accept a value `where($key, $value)` or an array of values `whereIn($key, $value)` to conditionally query the user.

```php
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
{
    if (empty($credentials) ||
       (count($credentials) === 1 &&
        array_key_exists('password', $credentials))) {
        return;
    }

    // First we will add each credential element to the query as a where clause.
    // Then we can execute the query and, if we found a user, return it in a
    // Eloquent User "model" that will be utilized by the Guard instances.
    $query = $this->newModelQuery();

    foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
        if (Str::contains($key, 'password')) {
            continue;
        }

        if (is_array($value) || $value instanceof Arrayable) {
            $query->whereIn($key, $value);
        } else {
            $query->where($key, $value);
        }
    }

    return $query->first();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Sample helper function:

```php
if (!function_exists('attempt')) {
    function attempt($credentials, $dates = [], $remember = false)
    {
        $user = User::where('email',$credentials['email'])->first();

        // if a date is null return false
        foreach ((array)$dates as $date) {
            if (is_null($user->{$date})) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return Auth::attempt($credentials, $remember);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```php
// single date
if (attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password],'activate_on')) {
    // ...
}

// array of dates
if (attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password],['activate_on','approve_on'])) {
    // ...
}

// no date
if (attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: And the solution here is to give up? :) it is good that you shared the code that is being called behind the scenes, it means that you know how to read the source code. But he is looking for solution here I guess :)

Comment: No, I just gathered from their profile that they were competent enough not to have their hand held with a basic-level workaround solution.  I explained why the method they wanted to use would not work.

Comment: It will not work. I want to add the condition like Not null or statement whereNotNull. can you please tell me how can I achieve this.

Comment: I think the laravel framework should provide such kind of feature as they official support the scalar value for comparing the user object like 'active' => 1 which is not suitable for every case. What do you think?

Comment: I agree it would be nice, but I don't think it's worth the effort to try to dig into the app.  I would write a simple helper function to achieve the desired behavior.  If you're interested, I have added an example above which accepts a date key (or keys []) as a second parameter.